# XEN How to put virtual machines in a directory other than /etc/xen

Tags: centos, redhat, xen

On my CentOS 5.2 box the XEN virtual machine configuration files have to be located
in /etc/xen to be started without specifying a path.
I want to move my virtual machines into /etc/xen/vm to separate them from the 
configuration files of the xen server.
Is there an easy way to change the default directory from /etc/xen to /etc/xen/vm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to follow [this tutorial](http://howtoforge.com/ubuntu-8.04-server-install-xen-from-ubuntu-repositories), use `xen-tools` to generate VMs for you, and specify where you want to put your VMs. You can then just modify a config file in there (`xen-tools.conf`) and change the dir property:

`dir = /etc/xen/vm`

There's a little extra work involved since you're on CentOS (and it's a lot easier if you're on Ubuntu), but it's still do-able.